# Going root when writing to file/saving file?

Tags: emacs, root, privileges

Is it possible to open a file(in root location) as non-root user in Emacs, edit it and then when its time to save provide the password so the Emacs can get write to the file? Better still provide different buffers with different user privileges?

I know of [`Tramp`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) but couldn't get my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
(require 'tramp)
(defun sudired ()
  (interactive)
  (dired "/sudo::/"))
```

You'll get a `dired` buffer where you have root privileges.
Any subsequent directory or file that you open from here will be with root.

Any other `dired` buffers will not be affected.

Comment: excellent. but any way to further streamline the process? Copying the file path, from `nautilus`, and then going to that path from within `dired` looks cumbersome.

Comment: Well, `dired` is the nautilus of Emacs. I don't use any other file managers:
I open all my pdf and videos from dired.

Comment: what about creating an new file? I see `dired-maybe-insert-subdir` but nothing for *file*

Comment: Just a regular `C-x C-f` while from a sudo dired buffer will do.

Comment: black-magic! How do I set the permission's of file's created through this, apart from using `M`? Because by default the files in root dirs are `644` while the ones created through this are `551`. Should this be a new question?

Comment: It's better style to post a new question. But I already have the answer:). It's `M-x chmod`.

Answer (score 3):

Update: I now use `sudo-edit` (available on Melpa or at https://github.com/nflath/sudo-edit), which has the header warning and is more robust than this function.

---

This is what I use.  You can open a file (even one that doesn't exist yet) or directory as a normal user, and run this function to get root privileges.

```
(defun find-alternative-file-with-sudo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((bname (expand-file-name (or buffer-file-name
                                     default-directory)))
        (pt (point)))
    (setq bname (or (file-remote-p bname 'localname)
                    (concat "/sudo::" bname)))
    (cl-flet ((server-buffer-done
               (buffer &optional for-killing)
               nil))
      (find-alternate-file bname))
    (goto-char pt)))
```

I also have this, which makes a big red banner across the top of the buffer telling me it's opened as root.

```
(defface find-file-root-header-face
  '((t (:foreground "white" :background "red3")))
  "*Face use to display header-lines for files opened as root.")

(defun find-file-root-header-warning ()
  "*Display a warning in header line of the current buffer.
This function is suitable to add to `find-file-hook'."
  (when (string-equal
         (file-remote-p (or buffer-file-name default-directory) 'user)
         "root")
    (let* ((warning "WARNING: EDITING FILE AS ROOT!")
           (space (+ 6 (- (window-width) (length warning))))
           (bracket (make-string (/ space 2) ?-))
           (warning (concat bracket warning bracket)))
      (setq header-line-format
            (propertize  warning 'face 'find-file-root-header-face)))))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'find-file-root-header-warning)
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'find-file-root-header-warning)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any special functions for this, it's built-in to Emacs (at least it is for version 24).

To open a file as root:

`C-x C-f` to open the `find-file` dialog in the minibuffer.

Then prepend `/su::/` to the file path:

`/su::/path/to/root/file`

You'll be prompted for the root password. After that, you can open the file as if you are root. The rest of your buffers will be unaffected. However, if you open another file *from the same buffer*, you'll automatically be opening it as root.

Comment: Better is to open with `/sudo::`.

Comment: @jcubic that depends on what you have in the sudoers config. Outside Ubuntu, sudo isn't necessarily enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have a way to open root files too, so I came up with this  function that replaced build in `find-file`, now I have this in my .emacs:

```
(defun test (&rest args)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (eq (apply 'call-process "test" nil (current-buffer) nil args) 0)))

(defun have-permission (filename)
  ;; only bash expand ~ with home directory
  (let ((expanded (replace-regexp-in-string "~"
                                            (concat "/home/" (user-real-login-name))
                                            filename)))
    (if (not (file-exists-p expanded))
        (let ((directory (file-name-directory expanded)))
          (and (test "-r" directory) (test "-x" directory) (test "-w" directory)))
      (and (test "-r" expanded) (test "-w" expanded)))))


(defun find-every-file (filename &optional wildcards)
  "Open file use sudo:: if user have no permissions to open the file"
  (interactive
   (find-file-read-args "Find All Files: "
                        (confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer)))
  (find-file (if (have-permission filename)
                 filename
               ;; you can replace that with /su:: if you don't have sudo access
               (concat "/sudo::" (file-truename filename)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'find-every-file)
```

It also work if you try to open non existing file or non existing file in directory you don't have write permissions.

you can combine it with @jpkotta warning popup.